# Name "userInput" cannot be defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm practicing some Python and i'm having some trouble trying to compare userInput would selected word in a hangman game.

```
# User guess input (single char)
# Exception handling to limit input to letters between a-z
while True:
    userInput = str(input('Please guess a letter:'))
    if len(userInput) == 1:
        if not re.match("^[a-z]*$", userInput):
            print("Error! Only letters a-z allowed!")
            continue
        break
    else:
        print("Error! Please input a single letter!")
        continue
# Comparing array with input
for i in range(len(selWord)):
    if(userInput == selWord[i]):
```

The problem lies in the in the last line:

```
        if(userInput == selWord[i]):
```

It states that  "The name 'userInput' is not defined." however when I try to print outside the initial while loop, it works fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, how do I exactly define it in a global scope? Thing is I'm pretty sure it's defined since I'm able to print it outside the while loop.

Comment: set `userInput = None` above `while` loop

Comment: Works fine for me if I define selWord at the top

Comment: That worked @stuartnox . Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you post and accept an answer, or close the question: right now it appears unanswered, which wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @greenasjade No one posted an answer, and I can't accept my own until 2 days. If you post "set userInput = None above while loop" as an answer, I will accept it as a solution. Sorry about that

Comment: Now there's an answer there: all good :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> set userInput = None above while loop

This was the solution, thank you everyone!

Comment: When I do this in my (equivalent) code, I get an inspection error in Intellij IDEA **redeclared "userInput" defined above without usage"**. Either way, my code seems to run fine, which is a bit unnerving. (Python3)